# Simulating PIC16F877A with MPLAB XC8 trouble resetting port with push button

Tags: controller, embedded, pic, mplab

```
void main(void) { 

    TRISB=0x07; 
    PORTB=0x00; 
    TRISD=0x00; 
    PORTD=0x00;  

    while(1) 
    { 
        if(RB0)  // when RB0 is high
        { 
            __delay_ms(100);
            PORTD++;    // PORTD increments, PORTD outputs to a LED
            __delay_ms(100); 
        } 

        if(RB2) //when RB2 is high
        {
            __delay_ms(100);
            PORTD = 0x00; // reset PORTD to 0
            break;
        } 
    } 

}
```

I am using the above code trying to reset `PORTD` when `RB2` goes high. I set my stimulus in MPLAB to send a 20ms pulse high signal to `RD0` or `RD2` when clicked, and observe the SFR value of `PORTD`.

`RD2` is supposed to clear `PORTD` when set high, but when I am watching the SFR value of `PORTD`, `PORTD` always increment first, then goes to 0 at the second click.

So let's say SFR value of `PORTD` is at 3, when RB0 is high, `PORTD` increment to 4, when `RD2` is high, it should go back to zero, but instead it goes to 5, and then goes to zero if `RD2` is high again.

How would I modify my code such that `RD2` resets `PORTD` immediately?

Comment: `break`will exit your `while`loop`. Is this what you want? Another issue: I guess you are mixing `RB2`and `RD2` in your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(RB0) // when RB0 is high 
{ 
   PORTD++; //Post increment 
}


if(RB2) //when RB2 is high
{
    
    PORTD = 0x00; 
    // Since ypu used post increment first PORTD will increment by 1 and then 
    it will be assigned 0
  
}
```

> How would I modify my code such that RD2 resets PORTD immediately?

solution: use pre-increment or PORTD = PORTD + 1;